# How to shift focus to file open / save dialog from full screen DirectX 11? (C++ VS2012)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, directx-11, fileopendialog

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit, DirectX11, and C++ in VS2012.
I am using the iFileOpen, and iFileSave dialog boxes in the winapi.

Please can anybody tell me how to show the dialog boxes when using directx in full screen mode.

The boxes are there if I use ctrl+alt+delete to show the task manager, and show the start bar. I can then select the file open / save dialogs from the start bar.

But that's not exactly a user friendly experience.

Can anyone advise how best to proceed in order to shift the focus to the dialog boxes automatically please.

Comment: I don't think you'll ever get this to be good user experience, unless you provide your own dialogs on your own UI, or are not full screen.

Comment: Alternatively, you could be "full screen", but really running in an always-on-top window that happens to take up the entire screen.

Comment: Your best bet is to use 'fake fullscreen' because a true display mode change will result in exactly the kind of focus problems you are describing.

Comment: Is there a way to switch to windowed, display the fileopen dialog, and then restore to windowed? I am a bit of a novice with DirectX, I know what I know from tutorials so there are gaps in my knowledge. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it I have discovered was to simply switch to windowed mode, allow the dialog to appear, and then immediately switch back to full screen when the dialog closes.

This tutorial here http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=11-4-4

Describes much better than I can how to do the switching.

Thanks for all the replies!